# What is the correct syntax for using Database.ExecuteSqlCommand with parameters on mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

Execute mysql stored procedure

```
  var affectedRows = 
      context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec UpdateStatus @p_customerId, @p_id",
            new MySqlParameter("p_customerId", "006"),
            new MySqlParameter("p_id", 9));
```

Get MySqlException

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'exec UpdateStatus
>   '006', 9' at line 1

When I try to replace stored procedure name with a Update statement it works. But I want to call a stored procedure instead.

I tried using  Entity Framework 5 and 6 same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Syntax of calling Stored Procedure from command is "CALL ". Also the parameters names should be having "@" in front.

So you need to change the code as as following.

```
var affectedRows = 
  context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CALL UpdateStatus (@p_customerId, @p_id)",
        new MySqlParameter("@p_customerId", "006"),
        new MySqlParameter("@p_id", 9));
```